# PMD java Scan report Github actions workflow

Tags: java, github-actions, cicd, pmd

I have the java code at following location - someRootFolder/someproject/src/main/java. And performing a static code analysis the Action runs and succeeds but no report.

How do I make sure it's working and report is generated for the files scanned.

Also looking to add a condition in case reports has failure block the code review request.

```
name: pmd-for-java
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} PMD
on: [push]
jobs:
  pmd-for-java-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # You may pin to the exact commit or the version.
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: '11'
      - uses: pmd/pmd-github-action@v1
        id: pmd
        with:
          version: '6.40.0'
          sourcePath: 'someRootFolder/someproject/src/main/java'
```